# Get-VM command is not always returning Notes for some reason?

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to write a simple PS script to get the list of VM's on a Hyper-V host and for some reason `Notes` are not always returned when `-ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters` is used. See Screenshot:

[image: See screenshot here].

Here are two different commands I'm using:

```
Get-VM | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters | Select-Object VMName,Status, IPAddresses,ComputerName, Hostname, Notes | Format-Table -AutoSize
Get-VM | Select-Object VMName,IPAddresses,ComputerName, Hostname, Notes | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

I'm trying to get:

- VM Name (`VMName`)
- VM's Status (Whether it's running/stopped. `Status` seems to work ok)
- The IPv4 address (I'm using `IPAddresses`)
- The VM's hostname (`ComputerName` and `Hostname` aren't currently working, I'll figure this out later)
- **Notes** on the vm (`Notes` doesn't always return a value)

So any idea why Notes do not always return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try and pipe `Get-VM | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters` to get-member it will not return the Notes Property. And thats why you can´t get it to display the notes.

You could instead make a pscustomobjet, maybe something like this.

```
$vms = Get-VM

ForEach ($vm in $vms) {
    [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
        'VMName'                   = $vm.Name
        'VM Status '               = $vm.Status
        'IP addresse'              = ($vm | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters).ipaddresses
        'Bytes Total/sec Ethernet' = $vm.computername
        'Bytes Total/sec WiFi'     = $vm.notes
    }    
}
```

/Anders